# how to handle Runtime Error: [ REQUEST_BUSY ] open-vino face recognition demo

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, openvino

def enqueue(self, input):
try:
self.clear()

```
    if self.max_requests <= self.active_requests:
        log.warning('Processing request rejected - too many requests')
        return False
        
    self.infer_queue.start_async(input,self.active_requests) #Error getting line 

    self.active_requests += 1
    return True
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```

Answer (score 0):

REQUEST_BUSY error arises when a request is not being processed and then asking for another infer/request. Refer to the [face_recognition_demo.py](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo/blob/master/demos/face_recognition_demo/python/face_recognition_demo.py) to see how the implementation is done. Your code is missing 'wait'.

Comment: I have referred to that link also but not working,    https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo/blob/master/demos/face_recognition_demo/python/ie_module.py
same come REQUEST_BUSY  and stuck the frames,

Comment: Please share all the necessary files and inputs to reproduce this issue from our end. You can put all the files in Google Drive and share the link here.

Comment: single camera working, but multiple cameras  input  using threading  cameras working, face false detection and above errors getting